# Get recurrence data of sharepoint calendar events using microsoft graph api?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

Is there a way to get recurrence information of sharepoint calendar events using the graph api? I can get the event fields using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-get?view=graph-rest-1.0) endpoint but I could not figure out a way to get event recurrence data of sharepoint calendar event using graph api.

If there's no way to do that, is there any documentation regarding working with sharepoint calendars? I could not really find any official documentation for it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about Graph, but here's what I know. There has always been a problem when it comes to expanding the recurrence data in calendar events - AFAIK there is no way to retrieve this piece of info using JSOM nor REST for item collections. It is possible though to get this information for a single item in a form of an XML. All you have to do is to fetch and read the `RecurrenceData` property of an item. Example endpoint URL:

`https://[tenantUrl]/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Events')/items(1)?$select=Title,RecurrenceData`

It will return something like the following in the `RecurrenceData` field:

```
<recurrence>
    <rule>
        <firstDayOfWeek>su</firstDayOfWeek>
        <repeat><daily dayFrequency="1" /></repeat>
        <repeatInstances>10</repeatInstances>
    </rule>
</recurrence>
```

You can try to fetch that property using the provided Graph endpoint but I don't know what the result will be and unfortunately I don't have a way to check it right now - sorry!

Also, have a look at this thread on the SharePoint StackExchange: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/23221/rest-api-expand-recurring-calendar-events?noredirect=1&lq=1

I've also recently stumbled upon a neat little library on Reddit, which simplifies common calendar tasks and allows to get this info using SOAP service. You can find it here: https://spcalendarpro.sharepointhacks.com/

Comment: Thank you for you answer. It's really no wonder Sharepoint was the most dreaded platform to work with in 2018 Stackoverflow Survey.
I will award this answer the bounty if there are no other answers. 
Any chance you would know if it's possible to access Shared Sharepoint Calendars via REST api? I don't see shared calendars listed in the lists [api](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn531433.aspx#bk_List).

Comment: Do you mean group calendars in O365?

Comment: No, someone from a different organization (xxxxxx.sharepoint.com) shared (gave read/write access to) a calendar that is in their organization. I belong to a different organization (let's say, yyyyy.sharepoint.com). I am trying to read events in that calendar using sharepoint api with my credentials. No success yet.

Comment: You might verify whether you have the Use Remote Interfaces permission level set for your account. Also, you might have to obtain the X-Request-Digest token from that tenant and then add it to your requests explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me to get RecurrenceData for a SharePoint calendar list in Azure using Graph API:

```
/v1.0/sites/root/lists/<list_guid>/items?$expand=fields($select=Title,RecurrenceData)
```